# Storing a token with a Redis async await function is not working. Does async await work on Redis?

Tags: node.js, redis

I am trying to store a token with Redis and retrieve it if it is there. If not, make a call to the server to get the token:

```
async function sendData (req, data, cb) {

let synchronyToken = await hb.redis.client.getAsync('synchronyToken-' + config.getEnv());

 if(synchronyToken === null) {
    await request({
        'method': authOptions.method,
        'url': authOptions.url,
        'proxy': authOptions.proxy,
        'body': authOptions.body,
        'headers': authOptions.headers
      }, (error, response, body) => {
        console.log(response);
        synchronyToken = response.access_token;
        hb.redis.client.set('synchronyToken-' + config.getEnv(), synchronyToken, {ttl: 3600});
      })
    }
}
```

Does await not work on Redis?

I am getting an error on:

```
let synchronyToken = await hb.redis.client.getAsync('synchronyToken-' + config.getEnv());
```

I afraid that if I just use

```
let synchronyToken = hb.redis.client.getAsync('synchronyToken-' + config.getEnv());
```

that my code will keep going and do a check on the synchony token without waiting for Redis to reply.

Comment: What error do you get on this? I have used async/await with redis and it works just fine.

Comment: Don't you have to use promisify for that with redis ? https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#native-promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you user node_redis library, there is no such function as client.getAsync unless you defined it using promisify like this:

```
const {promisify} = require('util');
const getAsync = promisify(client.get).bind(client);
```

you can also check ioredis library which supports async/await out of the box:

https://github.com/luin/ioredis